# Get the base branch and head branch from Pull Request in Bitbucket (GIT)

Tags: bitbucket, git-branch, branching-and-merging, bitbucket-api

I am using Bitbucket with Git and I want to know which is the head branch name of a Pull Request created into my repository programatically.

Based on https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.16.0/bitbucket-jira-rest.html it's possible to find the issues of a PR using its REST API (Endpoint: */rest/jira/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests/{pullRequestId}/issues*), but I could not find if there is another endpoint to get its corresponding branches. Is there a way to get the base and head branches of a PR from its *pullRequestId*?